# Flexbox - horizontal align - first item in the middle, second - left aligned

Tags: css, flexbox

```css
ul { 
  padding: 0; 
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
li {
  display: flex;
  margin: 1px;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #aaa;
}
li:last-child {
  background: #ddd;
  
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li>must always be in the center & occupy width of its text</li>
<li>text must start where 1'st item's text ends</li>
</ul>
```

I need first item to always be in the middle and occupy only the width of it's text; second item's text must begin exactly where the text of the 1st item ends.

https://jsfiddle.net/xa4yfbvb/

Comment: Also check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42455564/2827823

Comment: Here is an updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xa4yfbvb/5/

Comment: unfortunately the answers you've linked to don't help - I couldn't find a solution applicable to my prob. Re your fiddle - as I've stated in the question: I need first item to always be in the middle (**without padding or margins**); your fiddle has right padding on the 1st item

Comment: No, that is your fiddle, which I updated, with no right padding, so I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: Ok, I've used incorrect wording in the OP. (edited) What I need is that 1st item is centered and occupies only the width of it's text. And the 2nd item's text must begin exactly where the text of the 1st item ends.

Comment: Simple fix using the linked sources: https://jsfiddle.net/xa4yfbvb/6/

Comment: Parfait! :thumbsup: